# Can the Thorn Whip cantrip fulfill the requirement for the third benefit of the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, attack, melee-combat

As stated in the description for the [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) cantrip (PHB, p. 282), the caster makes a "melee spell attack" against the target.

> You create a long, vine-like whip covered in thorns that lashes out at your command toward a creature in range. Make a melee spell attack against the target.

The third benefit of the [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat says (PHB, p. 168):

> When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don’t provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

Given that the third benefit of the Mobile feat only requires a melee attack to be made to avoid provoking opportunity attacks (without specifying the type of melee attack), would that cantrip fulfill the trigger for Mobile?

In other words:
Is a spell melee attack considered a "melee attack" for the purpose of the Mobile feat?

Comment: The more direct duplicate: "[How do melee spell attacks interact with the Mobile feat?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/165002)"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Yes.

Besides seeming obvious, Jeremy Crawford also [answered a question about this](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/633398322317758464) in regard to Cleric's Touch of Death.

> A melee spell attack is, indeed, a melee attack

Answer (score 12):

A melee spell attack is considered a melee attack, even if it is done via a spell. The PHB/basic rules describe [melee attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) as follows (emphasis mine):

> Used in hand-to-hand combat, a melee attack allows you to attack a foe within your reach. A melee attack typically uses a handheld weapon such as a sword, a warhammer, or an axe. A typical monster makes a melee attack when it strikes with its claws, horns, teeth, tentacles, or other body part. **A few spells also involve making a melee attack.**

This is confirmed by the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=14), which says:

> **Does a melee spell attack count as a melee attack for Touch of Death?** A melee spell attack is, indeed, a melee attack and can qualify for the Death cleric’s Touch of Death feature.

Hence, the [*Thorn Whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) spell (as any other spell involving a melee attack) completely fulfills the requirement for the Mobile feat.

Answer (score 8):

### A melee spell attack is a melee attack

The *Player's Handbook* and Basic Rules have the following description in the Combat section on [melee attacks](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#MeleeAttacks) (emphasis mine):

> Used in hand-to-hand combat, a melee attack allows you to attack a foe within your reach. A melee attack typically uses a handheld weapon such as a sword, a warhammer, or an ax. A typical monster makes a melee attack when it strikes with its claws, horns, teeth, tentacles, or other body part. **A few spells also involve making a melee attack**.

Moreover, when the rules choose to distinguish between a "spell attack" and a "weapon attack", they do so explicitly. This is seen in a few other feats; one example is the [Charger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/charger) feat (PHB, p. 165; emphasis mine):

> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make one **melee weapon attack** or to shove a creature.

The [Mobile](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/mobile) feat does not choose to distinguish in this way, so any melee attack applies, including melee spell attacks.

Answer (score -1):

Yup. The feat mentions just melee attack, and melee spell attacks are melee attacks. For it not to work it must have specified melee **WEAPON** attack. In that case it would also exclude unarmed strikes as well

Comment: We do ask that answers be fully supported by either rules or subjective experience done or seen. You can read more about our [citation expectations here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8696). You're doing a great job in becoming active here, but please review your answers with the guidelines and expectations we review in the Meta linked above.