# How do melee spell attacks interact with the Mobile feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, attack, opportunity-attack

The Mobile feat states that:

> When you make a melee attack against a creature, you don’t provoke opportunity attacks from that creature for the rest of the turn, whether you hit or not.

Does that include melee spell attacks like *green-flame blade* or even *steel wind strike*?

So let's say you are surrounded by enemies and you cast *steel wind strike* and attack everyone around you. can you then safely walk out without provoking opportunity attacks?

Comment: Hi darnok, does that duplicate that Tiggerous found answer your question (in short, it concludes that a melee spell attack is a type of melee attack)?